Jump Buffering and Jump from Higher Platform Problem
I have implemented Jump Buffer into my code however it only works every now and then. I couldn't figure out the problem. I tried to send a debug message to see if the jump has been buffered or not.
Also, when i jump from a higher platform to a lower one and try to jump buffer, the character got frozen or boosted just a little before hitting the ground, it feels like when falling and closing on a ground, the vspd ( vertical speed ) get reset to 0 for a few frames and then it started to fall again.
There are a lot of if-statements as i am still new to coding and it's probably the easiest for me to understand and code.
Create :
///// Initial speed;

hspd = 0;
vspd = 0;
jspd = 5;
movespeed = 1.25;
max_movespeed = 1.25;
max_jspd = 10;
max_vspd = 10;

///// Physics

frict = - 0.25;
grav = 0.4;

///// Limits

j_limit = 0; 


///// jump buffer

jump_buffer_counter = 0;
jump_buffer_active = false;
jump_buffered_flag = false; 

Step :
//// debug
show_debug_message("Step started");


//// Checking if character on ground

if place_meeting(x, y + 1, obj_wall)
{
    on_ground = true;
    j_limit = 1;
}
else
{
    on_ground = false;
    j_limit = 0;
}

//// Movements

if keyboard_check(vk_right)
{
    hspd += movespeed;
}
if keyboard_check(vk_left)
{
    hspd -= movespeed;
}

//// Jump Buffering
            
if keyboard_check_pressed(vk_up)
{
    if (on_ground and j_limit == 1)
    {
        vspd = -jspd;
        j_limit = 0;
    }
    else if (!on_ground)
    {
        jump_buffer_active = true;
        jump_buffer_counter = 30;
        jump_buffered_flag = true;
    }
}

if jump_buffer_active == true
{
    jump_buffer_counter--;
    if jump_buffer_counter <= 0
    {
        jump_buffer_active = false;
    }
    else if on_ground
    {
        jump_buffer_active = false;
        jump_buffered = false;
        vspd -= jspd;
    }
}



show_debug_message("Jump Buffer Flag: x=" + string(jump_buffered_flag));
show_debug_message("Jump Buffer Timer: x=" + string(jump_buffer_counter));
        
//// Gravity

vspd += grav;

//// Clamp Move Speed

hspd = clamp(hspd, - max_movespeed, max_movespeed);

if keyboard_check(vk_up)
{
    vspd = clamp(vspd, - jspd, max_vspd);
}


if (!keyboard_check(vk_right) and !keyboard_check(vk_left) and hspd > 0)
{
    hspd += frict;
    if hspd == 0
    {
        hspd = 0;
    }
}
else if (!keyboard_check(vk_right) and !keyboard_check(vk_left) and hspd < 0)
{
    hspd -= frict;
    if hspd == 0
    {
        hspd = 0;
    }
}       


//// Collisions

if place_meeting(x + hspd, y, obj_wall)
{
    hspd = 0;
}
if place_meeting(x, y + vspd, obj_wall)
{
    vspd = 0;
}

//// Update X and Y positions 
//// debug
            
show_debug_message("Before position update: x=" + string(x) + ", y=" + string(y));
show_debug_message("Before position update: hspd=" + string(hspd) + ", vspd=" + string(vspd)+         ", gravity=" + string(grav));
x += hspd;
y += vspd;

if keyboard_check_pressed(vk_escape)
{
    //// debug
    show_debug_message("Exiting game...");

    game_end()
}

What I'm trying to get is the jump to buffer consistently if the arrow-Up key is pressed mid-air a few frames before hitting the ground. As well as, To fix the jump problem with the platforms.

For the Step Event, I think it's better to create debug messages real-time through draw_text() function in the drawGUI Event instead of using show_debug_message(), that makes it easier to see what the values are at the very moment in-game.

Platform collisions, my old nemesis.
Try replacing this part:
if place_meeting(x + hspd, y, obj_wall)
{
    hspd = 0;
}
if place_meeting(x, y + vspd, obj_wall)
{
    vspd = 0;
}

With this:
if (place_meeting(x + hspd, y, obj_wall))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x+sign(hspd), y, obj_wall))
    {
        x += sign(hspd)
    }
    hspd = 0;
}

if (place_meeting(x, y + vspd, obj_wall))
{
    while (!place_meeting(x, y+sign(vspd), obj_wall))
    {
        y += sign(vspd)
    }
    vspd = 0;
}

That way, it'll close the gap between your object and the wall that it otherwise would've crossed through it's speed.
As for your jump buffering: I once had accidently created a jump buffer by turning the keyboard_check_pressed into keyboard_check, so it always checks whenever you're holding down the key, the on_ground prevents it from accidently triggering multiple times. Maybe this may work for you too, but that depends on your jumping code.
